# php writing additional lines to encrypted files?

Tags: php, file, encryption, xor

I'm trying to open an encrypted file that will store a list of information, then add a new ID with information, and save the file back as it was originally encrypted. I have xor/base64 functions that are working, but I am having trouble getting the file to retain old information.

here is what I am currently using:

```
$key = 'some key here';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$group = $_GET['group'];
$file = "groups.log";
$fp = fopen($file, "w+");
$fs = file_get_contents($file);


$filedec = xorstr(base64_decode($fs),$key);

$info = "$id: $group";
$filedec = $filedec . "$info\n";
$reencode = base64_encode(xorstr($filedec,$key));

fwrite($fp, $reencode);
fclose($fp);



function xorstr($str, $key) {
$outText = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);)
  {
    for($j=0;$j<strlen($key);$j++,$i++)
    {
        $outText .= $str[$i] ^ $key[$j];
    }
  }
  return $outText;
}


?>
```

It should save an entire list of the ID's and their corresponding groups, but for some reason it's only showing the last input :(

Comment: Your code is currently overwriting the file with each execution, is that intended? (the `w+` mode)

Comment: Why don't you use `file_out_contents()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call this encryption. "cereal box decoder ring", maybe. If you want encryption, then use the [mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) functions. At best this is obfuscation.

The problem is that you're doing `fopen()` before doing file_get_contents. Using mode `w+` truncates the file to 0-bytes as part of the fopen() call. So by the time file_get_contents comes up, you've deleted the original file.

```
$fs = file_get_contents(...);
$fh = fopen(..., 'w+');
```

in that order will fix the problem.